# Загрузка первоначального содержимого элемента GRID из кода

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть центральный элемент GRID, в котором динамически показываются данные.
В самом начале в этом элементе находится краткое описание и ссылки
на различные разделы, но в ходе работы я удаляю все изначальное содержание
элемента с помощью `Children.Clear();`.

Есть ли какая-то возможность загрузить в элемент первоначальное содержимое,
которое находится в элементе при загрузке приложения и написанно xaml
из кода во время работы приложения?

А то, писать на с# разметку не очень приятная перспектива.

Comment: Как вариант, вернуть то, что оттуда удалили? Вы же можете в памяти сохранить контролы, что удаляете из представления

Comment: `писать на с# разметку не очень приятная перспектива` - потому, что это в WPF совершенно неверный подход. Там для таких целей есть XAML (View)...

Comment: Посмотрите примеры с `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать (наружный Grid для демонстрации работы, внутренний как раз ваш, очищаемый, обратите внимание, что все корректно размещается в те же ячейки, т.к. это те же самые компоненты, что были в этом гриде):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbShow" Unchecked="rbShow_Unchecked" Margin="5" IsChecked="True">Видно</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="rbHide" Unchecked="rbHide_Unchecked" Margin="5">Не видно</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="exampleGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Я в левом столбце" />
        <TextBlock Text="Я в правом столбце" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

А вот обработчики скрывающие и возвращающие элементы:

```
private List<UIElement> _elements = null;

private void rbShow_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _elements = new List<UIElement>(exampleGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>());
    exampleGrid.Children.Clear();
}        

private void rbHide_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    exampleGrid.Children.Clear();
    _elements.ForEach(item => exampleGrid.Children.Add(item));
}
```

Теперь при выборе RadioButton-а у вас компоненты быдут то видны, то нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но так делать не надо, по хорошему надо в WPF использовать MVVM и просто в форму подсовывать разные ViewModel и для них через ресурсы задавать разные View